# Microsoft Silverlight Unit testing framework can I inject javascript file into the test page

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, frameworks, silverlight-3.0

I want to write some tests that involve communicating from javascript from Silverlight and I want to know if it is possible to inject javascript at runtime?

So in my test project I have the following method in the app.xaml file and I want to be able to dynamically include\insert some javascript.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
     RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();
}
```

Cheers

AWC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some research into

`HtmlPage.Window.Eval(...)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlwindow.eval(VS.95).aspx

Also, I wouldn't recommend setting up the Javascript within your Application_Startup — of course I don't know your requirements.

I would recommend placing it with in your test specific code. Or test setup and when done with the test, clean up any Javascript code you inject.